# The ultimate goal is to create a dictionary where duplicated names are combined into one key and its value is multiple elements

Tags: python, string, loops, dictionary

I have a list which went through a for loop in order to produce each element separately as a string. Next, I created a variable to split those strings in order to get the key=pairs (resulting in multiple lists). Basically those lists only have two elements, [0] to be used as the keys and [1] to be used as the values.
How do I convert those lists into dictionaries where the duplicated keys are combined and their [1]s are their value?
I am new to this so please no fancy codes like def. Think basic.

```
lst = ["help-please" , "desperate-fix", "help-today", "desperate-need"]
for i in lst:
    a = i
    b = a.split("-")
    c = b[0]  #keys
    d = b[1]  #values
    e = {c:d} #how do I fix this to one key to many values? I believe this should be a loop to 
             facilitate many key:value pairs
```

My ulitmate goal:

```
e = {"help": ["please", "today"], "desperate": ["fix", "need"]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
lst = ["help-please" , "desperate-fix", "help-today", "desperate-need"]
ret_dict = {}
for i in lst:
    a = i
    b = a.split("-")
    c = b[0]  #keys
    d = b[1]  #values
    if c in ret_dict.keys():
        ret_dict[c].append(d)  # If key already exists then append to list
    else:
        ret_dict[c] = [d]      # else make new list and add d as the first element

print(ret_dict)
```